# javascript new date get time cant compare them

Tags: javascript

In my back-end, I update user last activity with:

```js
{ last_active: new Date().getTime() }
```

And on front-end, I did this:

```
const statusexpire = props.last_active + 1000 * 60;
const currenttime = new Date().getTime();
    
useEffect(() => {
  if (currenttime > statusexpire) {
    socket.emit('deletelogged', props.id);
    console.log('deleted' + props.id)
  }
}, [currenttime, props.id]);
```

But it looks like there's something wrong done, I tried several examples but didn't solve this.

Updating log for console.log(currenttime, statusexpire) just to see output:

```
1616162621335 "161616127040960000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621338 "161616262117760000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621345 "161616127040960000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621346 "161616262117760000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621398 "161616127040960000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621400 "161616262117760000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621410 "161616127040960000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621416 "161616262117760000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621425 "161616127040960000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621427 "161616262117760000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621435 "161616127040960000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621440 "161616262117760000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621447 "161616127040960000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621449 "161616262117760000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621456 "161616127040960000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621460 "161616262117760000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621466 "161616127040960000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621468 "161616262117760000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621482 "161616127040960000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621491 "161616262117760000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621497 "161616127040960000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621502 "161616262117760000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621513 "161616127040960000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621519 "161616262117760000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621527 "161616127040960000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621528 "161616262117760000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621535 "161616127040960000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621541 "161616262117760000"
UserItem.js:40 1616162621549 "161616127040960000"
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong? What values you have _inside_ `useEffect` of `currenttime` amd `statusexpire`

Comment: Just a socket that sends to server so i can remove from array offline userid, i think that i format bad dates ? And when i try to console.log(currenttime > statusexpire) theres no return

Comment: Can you do `console.log(currenttime, statusexpire)` inside your `useEffect` just before `if` and update question with output? Maybe you are not even calling that function?

Comment: I edited with output :)

Comment: Look you output, error is quite clear... Every "number" ends with 60000...

Comment: thanks for help, it was my bad :)

Comment: See, debugging your code may save lots of time before you go to SO to post for help :)

Comment: I added one more comment on bottom with full code , still didnt solve this fully..

Answer (score 0):

Seems `props.last_active` is String.
How about trying

```
const statusexpire = parseInt(props.last_active) + 1000 * 60;
```

Comment: I added one more comment on bottom with full code , still didnt solve this fully.

Comment: Since Array.filter() does not change array itself, you should use `loggedlist = loggedlist.filter(value => value !== data);`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is connected to the fact that `props.last_active` is not a number but a string so `props.last_active + 1000 * 60` returns `props.last_active` concatenated with `1000 * 60`.

To solve it's just necessary to convert `props.last_active` into an integer before sum it to `1000 * 60`:

```
const statusexpire = parseInt(props.last_active) + 1000 * 60;
```

Comment: I added one more comment on bottom with full code , still didnt solve this fully.